# why do RUBY DNS Queries output appended with a 'nil'?

Tags: ruby

while performing DNS Queries in `ruby` ,the end output is added with a "nil",what does that refer to ? or is it just a denotation of End of Line or so ?

Code :

```
require 'resolv'
Resolv::DNS.new.each_address("google.com") { |addr| puts addr }
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `each_address` just do processing of the code passed in the block. This does not return anything, that's why you are seeing `nil` in the end.

From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/Resolv/DNS.html#method-i-each_address):

> each_address(name)
>
> Iterates over all IP addresses for name retrieved from the DNS resolver.

Answer (score 0):

`each_address` just iterates over all IP addresses for name retrieved from the DNS resolver and doesn't return anything, so you got `nil`

Answer (score 0):

This code returns nil because [`puts` returns nil](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-puts).